# Why the dictionary sometimes is empty? (saving data in tornado.web.Application class instance)

Tags: python, dictionary, tornado

I am trying to pass some data between requests in tornado. I have a variable called `tcp_con`.

```
class Application( tornado.web.Application ):
    def __init__( self, **overrides ):
        handlers = [
            ( r"/", hd.MainHandler ),

            ]

        settings = { "cookie_secret": "thisismysecret",
                    "login_url": "/auth/login",
                    "template_path":  os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), "templates" ),
                    "static_path": os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), "static" ),
                    "xsrf_cookies": True
                    }

        # Initializing variables        
        self.debug = overrides['debug']
        self.__is_running_checks = False
        self.tcp_con = {}
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
```

I fill up with some variables when the use submited a form, but when I am refreshing the page the `tcp_con` variable is empty, if I refresh again then the dictionary contains the data again, so sometimes the values are in the dictionary, sometimes are not. What can be the problem?

This is the part of the request handlet:

```
@tornado.web.authenticated 
def get( self ):
    """
    """                    
    print self.application.tcp_con
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be doing something with `handlers` and `settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have more than one tornado process on server. Each process have own `Application` class. On request you can get response from different process. So, you cant use this class to save state of your application.

From tornado documentation ([class tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html#tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer.start)):

```
start(num_processes=1)
```

> Starts this server in the IOLoop.
>
> By default, we run the server in this process and do not fork any
>   additional child process.
>
> If num_processes is None or <= 0, we detect the number of cores
>   available on this machine and fork that number of child processes. If
>   num_processes is given and > 1, we fork that specific number of
>   sub-processes.
>
> Since we use processes and not threads, there is no shared memory
>   between any server code.

Comment: I also tried to replace with global variable, with the same result.

Comment: @run if you indeed have serveral processes, you cant share data between them with globals. Each process have own environment. You can try files, memcached, redis or something else...

Comment: No, a Queue is also an in-process data structure, so it isn't shared between processes. Use a database like Redis, MongoDB, etc.

Comment: That was the problem, after I `server.start(0)`  # autodetect number of cores and fork a process for each. I am using 1 instead of 0 and it is working as I expected.